# Need help setting up a curl command to fill in a form. Server responds with HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required after a 302 redirect

Tags: curl, post, http-status-code-302, http-status-code-411

I am trying to write a batch script which will alow users to easily fill in a police form about illegal fireworks. It takes some personal information about the user and uses this in combination with the current date and time to create a statement for the police. The personal information is also filled into the form so they can be contacted later.

When issuing a POST request, the server replies with a 302 status code. Therefore I used the -L flag in curl to make it follow the redirect.

The server, however, then responds with a 411 status code (length required) after this redirect.

For added context I am using curl version 8.0.1 (Windows) libcurl/8.0.1 Schannel WinIDN

Things I have already tried:

1. Using GET instead of POST.
2. Using the --post302 flag, an infinite loop results.
3. Adding the "Content-Length: 0" header results in HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden response.

My batch script is the following:

```
:: First we set some variables such as name, place, date, time, etc (omitted here)

...

:: We then use these variables to create the 'data' variable
set data="melding_bericht=%melding_bericht%&plaats_voorval=%plaats_voorval%&straat_voorval=%straat_voorval%&bestanden=&voornaam=%voornaam%&tussenvoegsel=%tussenvoegsel%&achternaam=%achternaam%&straatnaam=%straatnaam%&huisnummer=%huisnummer%&huisnummer-toevoeging=%huisnummer_toevoeging%&postcode=%postcode%&woonplaats=%woonplaats%&telefoonnummer=%telefoonnummer%&email=%email%&transmit=Versturen"

:: Now issue the request to the server
curl "https://www.politie.nl/aangifte-of-melding-doen/meldformulier-vuurwerkoverlast.html" ^
  -X POST ^
  -L ^
  -H "authority: www.politie.nl" ^
  --data %data% ^
  --verbose
```

Some logs from the curl process:

First the server responds with:

`HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily`

Then:

```
Issue another request to this URL: 'https://www.politie.nl/aangifte-of-melding-doen/meldformulier-vuurwerkoverlast.html? (the data in the form, omitted here)'

* Switch from POST to GET
* Found bundle for host: 0x21c63c12c50 \[serially\]
* Re-using existing connection #0 with host www.politie.nl

> POST /aangifte-of-melding-doen/meldformulier-vuurwerkoverlast.html?(the urlencoded data in the form, omitted here) HTTP/1.1
```

After this, the server response is:

`HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required`

Anyone know why

1. curl seems to do another post request? Even though it says switch from POST to GET before
2. If not, the server is expecting a content-lenght for a GET request?

Comment: This looks weird. Even though Curl appears to be doing a POST request all the form data is now in the URL as query params and not sending any content, or including a Content-Length header. This feels like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Having a dig around the Internet uncovered this issue on GitHub: [Invalid HTTP message when redirecting POST by 302](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/2554). which lead me to the `--post302` option.

Taking a look at the [documentation for the `-L' option](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-L)

> When curl follows a redirect and if the request is a POST, it sends the following request with a GET if the HTTP response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response code was any other 3xx code, curl resends the following request using the same unmodified method.
>
> You can tell curl to not change POST requests to GET after a 30x response by using the dedicated options for that: --post301, --post302 and --post303.

Which suggests that you should probably include the `--post301`, `--post302` and `--post303` options to enforce resending of the POST body.

Either way it does look like Curl seems to be getting a little confused by the redirect. As far as I can tell there's nothing in the [HTTP/1.1 spec, section 6.4.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.4.3 - 302 FOUND) that means the a redirect *should* be changed to a GET request:

> Note: For historical reasons, a user agent MAY change the request
> method from POST to GET for the subsequent request.  If this
> behavior is undesired, the 307 (Temporary Redirect) status code
> can be used instead.

Although it doesn't go in to what the "historical reasons" are!

Comment: Thank you! When I added those three flags I got a different response. Still not a 201 or something like that but instead a 400 status code (bad request). I am not sure why this would be, could there be an error with the encoding of the data? The HTML body of the response is "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand."

Comment: Take a look at the [--verbose option](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-v) it may shed some light on what is actually being sent.

Comment: It's also possible that there are some other protections in place to prevent automation of the forms, for example to prevent being DOS'd which would require you to include extra information in the request. This would be beyond the scope of the question though.

Comment: I hope thats not the case, otherwise this will be difficult. Can they distinguish a request that comes from a browser or curl if you set the headers to the correct values?

I have used the --verbose option but it does not show the contents of what is being sent.

Interestingly, it seems that the first redirect adds some data such as a cookie with INGRESSCOOKIE and JSESSIONID variables and an 'sid' variable that is put in the redirect url.

Comment: I made an error before, the content-length header was set to 0. So I changed the curl command to:

'curl "https://www.politie.nl/aangifte-of-melding-doen/meldformulier-vuurwerkoverlast.html" ^'
'  -X POST ^'
'  -L ^'
'  --data %data% ^'
'  --post301 ^'
'  --post302 ^'
'  --post303 ^'
'  --verbose'

This yields an infinte loop where it keeps redirecting and appending the data to the end of the url each time!

Comment: Without any official API documentation of the host site, what you're doing may be against the terms of use/service of the site. Remember that without an official API the URLs and forms you are posting may change without notice breaking your code.

Comment: Yeah, I will probably have to contact somoene who works on their servers to see if I can fix it. They don't mind getting the statements as it allows them to allocate resources. That's what they told me at least.

Comment: Readers will always want to see your best version of code, so please update the body of your question with your revision now in the comments (and then delete the comment, to avoid unneccsary re-reading, please? (-;? ). Good luck.